# How to integrate Facebook in my AribaWeb WebApplication?

Tags: facebook

My web application is developed using AribaWeb framework and I want to integrate my application with Facebook. I need to post some info to my product's wall when i'm saving my sample page. I have some doubts to do this,

1. Is there any need of Web services. if so what are they?
2. Is it possible to do without JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Study the facebook API. I am sure there is a REST service that allows you to do that. Then you can send a REST request from your application using available REST frameworks such as RESTeasy or Jersey .